# How to make Angular 2 render HTML template after a promise in the component is resolved?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

For my app, the `ItemDetailComponent` is where info of an item will be displayed. I have a service that retrieves all items using promise. I use `ActivatedRoute` to retrieve the item ID from the url path, then run the service, get all items, then find the item with the ID retrieved above, and assign it to `selectedItem` variable.

Here is `item-detail.component.ts`:

```
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  private title = 'Item Details'
  private selectedItem: object

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private itemService: ItemService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const selectedItemId = this.route.snapshot.params.itemId

    return this.itemService.getAllItems()
      .then((items) => {
        return _.find(items, item => item.itemId === selectedItemId)
      })
      .then((selectedItem) => {
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem
        console.log('Inside promise', this.selectedItem)
      })
    console.log('Outside promise', this.selectedItem)
  }
}
```

And here is `item-detail.component.html` template so I could display my item, just an example:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>

  <div *ngIf="selectedItem">
  <div><label>Item ID: </label>{{selectedItem.itemId}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The app returns nothing but the title unfortunately. I then added the two `console.log()` commands and found out that the one outside of the promise as well as the html template are rendered before the promise is fulfilled, and no `selectedItem` is available at that time. How could I force the app to execute them only after the promise is resolved in order to have the `selectedItem` in place for displayed?

**EDIT**: I added a new line in the html template to examine further:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div><label>Item ID 1: </label>{{selectedItem.itemId}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="selectedItem">
  <div><label>Item ID 2: </label>{{selectedItem.itemId}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The app displays "Item ID 1:" label but with no actual id there. The console shows me an error saying that "Cannot read property 'itemId' of undefined", again confirming that the whole template is rendered before promise resolved and is not re-rendered after data is loaded. So weird.

Comment: *"How could I force the app to execute them only after the promise is resolved in order to have the selectedItem in place for displayed?"*. You don't need to. Template will rerender automatically. The real question is do you get "Inside promise" log and `selectedItem` gets resolved properly?

Comment: Yes, the inside promise log shows me just fine the item that I want to display the details of.

Comment: is the title property bound ok? ca you post a plunkr pls

Comment: @Tsar yes `title` is bound okay. Lemme see if I could get it on plunkr quickly, never done that before.

Comment: Quite some trouble though cuz the item service retrieves info from a docker container that connects to a remote server in the dev.

Comment: Seem you have found your solution already, but just to make sure one thing. What you are expected is default supported by Angular. Which means that after the promise resolve, If you make any change on the variable that linked to UI. It will be updated automatically. In your case, I suspect that something went wrong on your promise handle, not the angular problem.
Check the plunkr here to see my example. Just create the promise which resolve data after 3 sec then update the data. You can see the UI updated too. 
http://embed.plnkr.co/EByTAmyUe1HczX73RVk3/

Comment: @trungk18 Yeah it struck me as well, I know the html template is re-rendered automatically if new data is loaded, that’s why I had absolutely no clue what went wrong. Your suggestion sounds like a good idea, I’d better check back with the promise handler and see what’s going there in the backend. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Resolver for the route that fetches the desired data.

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Working now with flying color. Got to learn a useful angular interface as well. Would totally recommend this solution to anyone having the same prob.

Comment: Super duper! Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean variable in to your class like

private dataAvailable:boolean=false;

and in the subscription to the promise,make this true when the data is available

```
then((selectedItem) => {
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
this.dataAvailable=true;
        console.log('Inside promise', this.selectedItem)
      })
```

and in the template render when the data is available

```
<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>

  <div *ngIf="dataAvailable">
  <div><label>Item ID: </label>{{selectedItem.itemId}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should do the trick

Comment: I just tried and it didn't help actually. I also thought it wouldn't work since both `selectedItem` and `dataAvailable` are assigned new values in the same promise at the same time so it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: as  dfsq pointed out,template should rerender once the data is available.!..Can you create a plunk for the same ?

Comment: Quite some work to make a plunker for this since the item service retrieves info from a docker container that connects to a remote server in the dev.

Comment: @Duc `getAllItems () { return Promise.resolve([{itemId: 1}, {itemId: 2}])}`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

`ngOnInit()` seems to be just a event handler hook - returning anything won't affect anything it seems. Hence my old answer will not work.

There are other workarounds like using *ngIf or putting it in routes etc. but I wish there was something like `resolvePromise(): Promise` hook that would put a condition on resolution before rendering.

This is instead of developers putting the boilerplate in every component.

**Old answer**

Most likely that is because you are missing return statement in the second `then`.

`then((selectedItem) => {
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem
        console.log():
        return selectedItem;// 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the `ChangeDetection` is set to `OnPush` somewhere up the component tree?
If that is the case, the template does not automatically rerender, because nothing triggers the `ChangeDetection` for this component.

Look out for a Component with the setting `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    template: `...`,
    styles: [`...`],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Also you already have a valid solution by using a `Resolver` you could check if this helps:

```
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    private title = 'Item Details'
    private selectedItem: object

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private itemService: ItemService,
        // the reference to the components changeDetector is needed.
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef 
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        const selectedItemId = this.route.snapshot.params.itemId

        return this.itemService.getAllItems()
            .then((items) => {
                return _.find(items, item => item.itemId === selectedItemId)
        })
        .then((selectedItem) => {
            this.selectedItem = selectedItem
            // this triggers the changedetection and the template should be rerendered;
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); 
            console.log('Inside promise', this.selectedItem)
        });
        console.log('Outside promise', this.selectedItem)
    }
}
```

Here is a great article about Angulars ChangeDetection: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html